# Parse signup error with swift 2 (xcode 7 beta 5)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, backend

I am using Parse and I have a signup page where I call:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

I checked and this works on previous versions of Xcode, however there was a similar problem when Swift 1.2 came out, though it doesn't solve my problem.

The error I get is:

```
Cannot invoke 'signupInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type: '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void )'
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the type of `succeeded` value to `ObjCBool`. The signature of `PFBooleanResultBlock` now changed `(Bool, NSError?) -> Void` to `(ObjCBool, NSError?) -> Void`

So you should change the type `Bool` to `ObjCBool`, like below:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: ObjCBool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print(succeeded)
    print(error)
}
```

or just remove the type to make the compiler inferring the type.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
    print(succeeded)
    print(error)
}
```